# Make bitmap partially invisible AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

I am trying to make a object (movie clip containing textfields and bitmaps) and I need to make it partially transparent at times (like making half of it disappear). How is it possible?

Comment: Have you heard of masking? Using the right caching on your objects (cache as Bitmap) will allow you to create masking that supports alpha channels.

Comment: @MartyWallace Could you provide some code?

Comment: 3 hours is a long moment, you must not work in Linux/internet time :) here's a bit about masking http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/ I think you should probably start trying to implement this yourself, then if you get stuck post your code and explain what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// only things inside the rect will be visible
DisplayObject.scrollRect = new Rectangle(...);
```

A MovieClip is also a DisplayObject.

Comment: Does this display with scroll bars though?